# ¿Cómo copio una versión de un fichero de una rama de git a otra?

Tags: git, git-merge, ramas-git

Resulta que estoy trabajando en la rama `feature-bla` y he cambiado unas cuantas cosas, con push incluido.

Me he dado cuenta ahora que necesito recuperar el contenido de un fichero que está en otra rama. Este fichero en mi rama actual ha sufrido muchas modificaciones con sus *commit* y *push* correspondientes, por lo que es algo tedioso ir deshaciéndolo.

¿Existe alguna forma de copiar un fichero concreto desde una rama determinada a mi rama actual?

Comment: asociación: https://stackoverflow.com/q/307579/1983854 No era la idea, pero me fue bien encontrarlo por trabajo y ya que estamos lo añado a SOes porque no veo pregunta similar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sí, debes hacer:

```
git checkout mi_otra_rama fichero.txt
```

Donde `mi_otra_rama` es la rama de donde quieres traer el fichero `fichero.txt`.

Más generalmente:

```
git checkout <commit_hash> <ruta_relativa_al_fichero_o_directorio>
git checkout <remote_name>/<branch_name> <fichero_o_directorio>
```

Algunas notas:

- usando el `commit_hash` puedes traer ficheros de cualquier commit.
- esto funciona tanto para ficheros como para directorios.
- esto sobrescribe el fichero `fichero.txt`.
- no funcionan los wildcards, pero sí las rutas relativas.
- puedes indicar múltiples rutas.

Publicación basada en [How do I copy a version of a single file from one git branch to another?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/307872/1983854)

Comment: Creo que es importante agregar que no se copia nada de la metadata de la rama _fuente_ del archivo que se está trayendo. Para git, es como si los cambios se hubieran hecho a mano directamente sobre el archivo local.